# IECAPT - screencapture - cannot capture webpage with silverlight image

Tags: screen-capture, silverlight

I am trying to use IECapt to capture a screenshot of a webpage that has silverlight elements but despite adding delays, It shows the silverlight area as a blank. Any ideas or alternative solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [iMacros for IE](http://www.iopus.com/imacros/compare/all/) "macro recorder" browser addon (free!) and then run this simple one line macro:

```
SAVEAS TYPE=PNG FOLDER=* FILE=screenshot_time_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd_hhnnss}}.png
```

It will [save the complete website as PNG file](http://wiki.imacros.net/Browser_Automation#Web_Site_Screenshot).

I quickly tested with a Silverlight page and it works fine:

[image]

PS: Same macro works in iMacros for Firefox

Answer (score 0):

See what [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/) makes of it.